# Switch between two layouts at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout which is mainly a linearlayout with a `Button` and another layout which is is a linearlayout again with an `EditText` and two buttons : Cancel and Submit.

What I want is initially the first layout to be displayed. When user clicks the button this layout is being replaced by the 2nd layout(the one with the two buttons).

I have already tried `ViewFlipper` but the problem is that it takes the height of the one with bigger height. So when first layout is displayed 
it has a big white space between the button and the content below it.

Comment: Why don't you use fragments? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: It doesn't sounds like a case that it will need fragments. Besides I'm already in a child Fragment

Comment: Child of the activity or another fragment? Couldn't you replace/add the child fragment with a fragment containing the second view?

Comment: Child of another Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using a `ViewFlipper` you can fix the height issue by adding this to your `ViewFlipper` in XML:

```
android:measureAllChildren="false"
```

Comment: Works as expected! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Layout1.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)
Layout2.setVisibility(VISIBLE)

Answer (score 0):

Try use only one layout and set VISIBLE or GONE:

```
View b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Or If you Have two layouts, use Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(i)
```